# Turn off payment option on second store front

Tags: payment-methods, stores

I have two storefronts and I need to disable payment on account for the second storefront. This doesn't appear possible in the admin (unless I'm missing something). What is the correct way to do this?

Comment: Do you want to disable a specific payment method? Or all of them?

Comment: which payment option you're using?

Comment: It is payment on account - this needs removing from the second storefront.

Answer (score 1):

Go to System > Configuration > Sales > Payment Methods

then in the left top corner of the page under Current Configuration Scope: select the storefront that you want to disable the payment option for. Now disable the payment method and save config.

Don't forget to switch back to the Default Config after you're done.

Answer (score 0):

Go to System - Configuration and then select the storeview you want to edit in the top left of your screen. There is a select with all the websites/stores/storeviews you have in your installation.

Go to Payment methods and disable the one you don't want to use in that particular store view.